# What happens if Date.now () is greater than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER?

Tags: javascript, date, numbers, unix-timestamp, integer-overflow

Of course it took another 200,000 years for that to happen. But will the *Javascript* dating system error after the value of `Date.now()` exceeds the value of `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`? What consequences will occur?

Maybe this question looks strange and useless. But can anyone answer my curiosity and also other people who might have the same question.

Comment: Epoch time returned from `Date.now` simply counts the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970. Have you ever wondered how to represent dates _before_ that time? Forget about 200,000 years into the future, that's just 50 years ago! Using an integer to represent a date is convenient, but it's not an implementation requirement. You have a long time to come up with another Date standard that supports a wider range of dates.

Comment: I've come from the year 202020 - javascript is no longer used, since we don't have web pages any more, we've evolved beyond such primitive forms of information transfer - all information is passed using odours

Comment: @JaromandaX Hahahaha

Comment: The computer explodes, be careful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you describe is ruled out by ECMA-262. The maximum value that can be returned by [Date.now](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-date.now) is ±8.64e15, which is well within the [range of integers safely supported](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-number.max_safe_integer) by ECMAScript.

The maximum value can represent 1e9 days either side of the epoch (1 Jan 1970) so a range of approximately ±273,790 years. I think there will be time to address the issue before it arises.

Constructing a date for the maximum value returns a date for +275760-09-13T00:00:00.000Z. Adding one millisecond to the time value returns an invalid date:

```js
// Max value returnable by Date.now
let maxDateNowValue = 8.64e15;

console.log(new Date(maxDateNowValue).toISOString()); // +275760-09-13T00:00:00.000Z

// Max value plus 1 millisecond
let plusOneMS = maxDateNowValue + 1;

console.log(new Date(plusOneMS).toString()); // Invalid Date
```

Comment: It's a great answer. @LaodeMuhammadAlFatih, why you did not accept it?

Comment: @TakesiTokugawaYD Done. Sorry. I forget to accept this.